# Assign values for every unique value in column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL with a column "country" in which there are 32 distinct string values, but far more rows

How is it possible to assign every unique string a specific numeric value (e.g. 'Austria' = 1, 'Australia' = 2,..., 'USA' = 32)
I could use the UPDATE statement, however, in this case, doing manually 32 countries is not a good way, I guess. I hope there is another way around.

Comment: Does your table have 32 rows each one with a different country, or many more rows but only 32 different [and repeated] values?

Comment: It has far more rows, but only 32 values in country column, and these values repeat

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the other question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, here in one method:

```
update country c
    set col = cc.seqnum
    from (select c.*, row_number() over (order by country) as seqnum
          from country c
         ) cc
    where cc.country = c.country;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily add a new ID column in the `country` table to cater for this.

See the syntax below:

```
Alter Table country
Add Id Int Identity(1, 1)
Go
```